# Fastest way to ssh a network range and return all machines whith hostname – master_server

Tags: linux, ssh, scripting

Constraints:

1. Speed matters.

We are searching for a tool or script as bash/python/perl , etc
that can ssh to the IP range from `10.xxx.xxx.xxx` to `10.254.254.254`
And find all machine hostname that have the hostname - `master_server`  , for example `master_server01` , `master_server02` etc

Example of expected results

```
10.2.3.22 master_server01
10.2.8.12 master_server27
.
.
.
```

Comment: You've asked for a way to do this with ssh, but have you considered avahi?  There's some discussion of it here: https://askubuntu.com/a/161687/39039

Comment: since we have rhel machines - 7.6 , without gui , then please explain how to use it?

Comment: First part of the suggested answer uses a command-line tool

Comment: Do you have to type a login/password on each machine ? Or ssh keys are deployed ?

Comment: Do you NOT want to query DNS for hostname, but rather ssh and ask the local machine what its hostname is?

Comment: about - "Do you have to type a login/password on each machine ? Or ssh keys are deployed " , yes I need to access with password ( while the user is root )  , so we can use with sshpass